# An analog input card can convert a -10V to +10V signal into a digital value of 0-27648

Tags: adc

An analog input card can convert a -10V to +10V signal into a digital value of 0-27648.

What is the digital value if the input signal is 0V?

digital output = (2^N * analog input voltage) / (reference voltage)

Will this formula work for this application?

Comment: As long as you remember the offset for bipolar ADCs, it should.

Answer (score 2):

For an input of 0 V the obvious digital output would be 27648 / 2. How will you generate that from your formula?

I don't know the device you have in mind but I suspect that the ADC will need both positive and negative references.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fobFtq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Output vs input.*

I'd go with

$$ out = 2^{n}\frac {V_{in}}{2V_{ref}}+ 2^{n-1} $$
$$ out = 2^{n}\left(\frac {V_{in}}{2V_{ref}}+ \frac 1 2\right) $$